# Trying to populate a TableView with retrieved data from a Firestore collection using Swift but it is empty

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I'm really new to IOS development using swift and I would like to know why I receive an empty TableView when I try to populate a TableView with retrieved data from a Firestore collection.

There are no errors at all. I receive data when I try

```
print()
```

Could it because of SnapshotListener?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Posts {
   var caption:String
}

class LentaViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var posts = [Posts]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadPosts()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
 }

 func loadPosts() {
    let dbUsers = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
    dbUsers.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                if let Caption = document.data()["caption"] as? String {
                    print(Caption)
                    var post = Posts(caption: "")
                    post.caption = Caption

                    self.posts.append(post)
                }

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print(self.posts)
        }
    }
  }
}

extension LentaViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = post.caption
    return cell
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assign the `tableView.dataSource` property to the `LentaViewController` instance. Assign it in `viewDidLoad()`. Also, no need to reload the tableView in `ViewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.dataSource = self
   loadPosts()
}
```